# Laravel Does Not Seem To Be Connecting With Controller Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have made this form at my Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('insertWallet') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="title" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="name" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="cashable" id="flexCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault" name="naghdi">
        &nbsp; Cash
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="active" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        &nbsp;Active
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deactive" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
        &nbsp; Deactive
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>    
</form>
```

And here is the route that I've called for inserting data:

`Route::post('wallets/insert','Wallet\WalletController@insert')->name('insertWallet');`

And then at the Controller, I tried this to test it works or not:

```
public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'active' => 'required'
        ]);

        dd($data);
    }
```

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

Comment: Set the `type="submit"` attribute on your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set value to radio button and change name

```
 <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"  value="active" name="active" id="flexRadioDefault1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                &nbsp;Active
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="active" value="deactive" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                &nbsp; Deactive
            </label>
        </div>
```

Since validation is redirecting back to same page.Always add validation message display block like below.For example for name to show validation message add like below

```
@error("name")
   <div class="invalid-feedback">{{$message}}</div>
@enderror
```